# Import formula from MS Access database to MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've been fighting for a long time with import formula record in database `(=45+5 or =SUM(D20:D23))` to Excel worksheet. My problem is when I import formula from database in Excel cell is raw text from database record `(=45+5 or =SUM(D20:D23))`.

It's fine, but I'm not able to calculate this formula. I've tried options in VBA after importing from database like:

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate, Worksheets(1).Calculate, ActiveWorkbook.Calculate
```

Only manual one manual option works. When I set to cell with formula and hit ENTER.

But I want to automate this process.

----EDIT----
Original code:

```
Sub GetDataFieldInfo()

  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim address_complete As String
  Dim address_column As Integer
  Dim address_row As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

db_file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Example_db.mdb"
  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
      ";Data Source=" & db_file & _
      ";Persist Security Info=False"
  conn.Open

  Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Students")
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
   
  address_complete = findCellAddress(rs(i).Name)
  address_row = Range(address_complete).Row
  address_column= Range(address_complete).Column

  rs.MoveFirst
j = 0
Do Until rs.EOF
    If InStr(1, rs.Fields(rs(i).Name), "=", 1) Then
    Cells(address_row + 1 + j, address_column).Formula = rs.Fields(rs(i).Name).Value
    Else
    Cells(address_row + 1 + j, address_column).Value = rs.Fields(rs(i).Name)
    End If
    j = j + 1
       rs.MoveNext
       Loop
  Next
      rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You could make use of the `Worksheet.Function` method and a loop to convert the cell value from text to a formula?

Comment: @SamuelEverson What Function should I use for more complex formula like `=IF(AND(H11="";I11="");0;IF(N11="";0;IF(H11="";ROUND(I11/(1+DATA!$A$3)*N11;2);H11*N11)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably doing Range("A1") = "=SUM(D20:D23)".

Instead of this you should do Range("A1").value = "=SUM(D20:D23)".

If this is not the case, please show us the VBA code you are using to export from msaccess to excel. It will help a lot.

Comment: thanks for response. Finally after 4 hours of searching internet I found a solution `Cells(row+ 1 + j, column).Formula = rs.Fields(rs(i).Name).Value`